# Google Maps - Use marker for end point while creating object using drawingManager

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I wan to use `marker` as end point while creating object on `google map` using `drawingManager` library.

Currently its working fine but it place simple dot as end point on `google map` but instead of that I want to use my custom marker.

Currently when I create an `object` then it display like this :

[image]

But instead of that simple end point i want to use marker like this :

[image]

I have used this code from `google map` library.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools

Answer (score 0):

You can use BitmapDescriptorFactory; something like this :-

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                                    new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).icon(
                                    BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                            .fromResource(R.drawable.end_icon))

);
```

You can use any custom image for that.